# ssrs calendar not showing on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm getting trouble showing ssrs datetime picker, since the calendar is not showing on chrome. Is there a way to make this working? 
(all reference i got was broken links to http://www.rajbandi.net/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use IE tab with Chrome.  SSRS is not meant to run on anything but IE and IE for some reason does not like it's own products at times do to way way way too much security built in for non sensible reasons.

IE Tab for Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en

I work on SSRS day in and day out and I never use IE unless forced to.